# Wait for another function to be executed in flask python

Tags: python, flask

I'm relatively new to flask.

I've 2 functions as below.

```
@app.route('/auth', methods=['GET'])
def get_auth():
   ....


@app.route('/identity', methods=['GET'])
def get_identity():
   ....
```

`get_identity` needs some variables that are created only after `get_auth` is executed. Is there a way to control the flow such that `get_auth` runs first and then `get_identity` runs. Currently both functions are triggered by a button click.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

inside of get_auth() method use redirect:

```
redirect(url_for('get_identity'), args)
```

where args are variables you want to handle them inside get_identity() method.

## some changes to get_identity() method:

```
@app.route('/identity', methods=['GET'])
def get_identity(args):
   ...
```